# python: check for variable redefinitions as loop variables

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

In python you can create rather hard to find bugs by giving a loop variable a name that already exists in the rest of your code.

The pattern looks like this:

```
idx = 0 # the result of some calculations

for idx in range(10):
    # do something

# use idx and expect it to be 0
# surprise, idx is actually 9
```

Of course, the obvious solution is to have better variable names. But even if you use very descriptive names, there is still a chance that the same name seems like a good choice somewhere else in your code.

Especially in numerical code, there are just so many indices that it gets really hard to keep track. And variables pretty much never run out of scope:

```
for idx in range(10):
    # do something

# idx is now in scope
# autocomplete will suggest idx, but it is still fine as a loop variable
for idx in range(10):
    # do something
```

Is it possible to set up a linter for this problem ?

I want to be warned whenever I use a variable as a loop variable that has been defined in an enclosing scope. The rule would need a notion of scopes and their child-scopes. The first code sample above should create a warning. In the second example, the loop variable already exists in the outer scope, but it has been defined in a child of the enclosing scope. That should be fine.

Comment: Speaking for a friend here :P (and he doesn't find your comment very constructive ...)

Comment: I think it is much better to learn to organize your code appropriately rather than relying on a linter to allow you to continue writing disorganized code. my 2 cents. take them or leave them. Writing well-organized code will help you more than any linter.

Comment: Note also, in your examples, you say: "In the second example, the loop variable already exists in the outer scope, but it has been defined in a child of the enclosing scope. That should be fine." There are no outer scopes or enclosing scopes. You are working with a single scope: the global scope.

Comment: Speaking for those of us who spend significant time reviewing other engineer's code, I think this would be a great feature for a linter. Speaking as an engineer trying to avoid this sort of problem, I try to avoid looping over indices, preferring list.map when possible.

Comment: It should be reasonably straightforward to do this with `dis`, at least for single-target `for` loops.  (It’s easier to deploy on a function than a module, although both are possible.)  Did you want help with *that*?